# cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am learning C# and obviously having problem running my program, as I am running this on 'Ubuntu', means no Visual studio, but on Visual Studio code, so having problem with debugging stuff.

```
namespace BeginnerCSharp;

class Program        
{
    string testUser = "User 1";
    int age = 15;   

    void printMessage()
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        int user_age = program.age;
        if (user_age == 15)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are very young");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(program.printMessage());
    }
}
```

I am getting following error, at `printMessage()`

```
cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'
```

What seems to be the problem, since I am not returning anything at all.

Comment: I don't think that your code is compilable. You will get error: *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.printMessage()'*. You need to create a `Program` instance to call the `printMessage` method and the `Console.WriteLine()` is not needed.

Comment: Where `cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'` come from ? From a visual code tip box or when you try to compile ? .. If it comes from the compilation, could you try to update the signature of the main method with `statis bool Main(string[] args)` and add a `return true` at the end. Ubuntu programme could be requiring a result for the run of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(printMessage());
}
```

In your code : Console.WriteLine(printMessage());
This above line is giving the error: **cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'**

***As Console.WriteLine() function expects some value.
But printMessage()  is returning void thus you are getting that error.***

There are 2 ways to get past the error:

1. In this case you don't have to write:
   Console.WriteLine(printMessage());

   you can directly call the function as below :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Program program = new Program();

      program.printMessage();
  }
```

2. You can return something from **printMessage()**
   Something like this:

> ```
>  int  printMessage()
>  {
>      Program program = new Program();
>      int user_age = program.age;
>      if (user_age == 15)
>      {
>          Console.WriteLine("You are very young");
>      }
>      return 0;
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

When your code modified as below then the `CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'` compile error is displayed.

```
static void printMessage()
{
    Program program = new Program();
    int user_age = program.age;
    if (user_age == 15)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You are very young");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(printMessage());
}
```

The problem is that all overloads of the `Console.WriteLine` method (except for the parameterless one) requires a value. Since `printMessage()` method has `void` return type (does not return any value), the line

```
Console.WriteLine(printMessage());
```

gives the error you provided. If you change the `printMessage()` method so that it returns a `bool`, `int`, `double` etc. then it will compile. Just make sure that your return type matches one of the `Console.WriteLine()` overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Alright someone commented the correct answer and the removed it.. Yes, I have to remove `Console.WriteLine` from `Main` Method. and It worked.